# Prototyped function isn't defined?

Tags: c++, function, prototype, codeblocks

So I've got a project file in CodeBlocks for Project Euler, but I'm a bit confused about what I've done wrong in setting my code up. I have a main.cpp file for running my programs, and I prototype each problem's function before I use it in the main block. However, I have this error when trying to build it:

||=== Build: Debug in Project Euler (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
C:\Users\under\cpp-workspace\Project Euler\main.cpp|9|undefined reference to`p4()'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

This is what I have, so I'm not sure what's wrong?

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void p4();

int main()
{
    p4();
    return 0;
}
```

p4.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void p4()
{

    cout << "hello there" << endl;

}
```

I'm not sure what's wrong?

My question is not a duplicate, at least not that I can tell. The question this is supposedly a duplicate of never mentions the issue I'm having.

Comment: You didn't add `p4.cpp` to your project

Comment: Yes I did. They're both in the same project.

Comment: Maybe you tried to build main.cpp instead of building your project

Answer (score 0):

> I've checked, and p4() is a void function with no inputs, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

You have declared `p4()` but you haven't defined it. Add

```
void p4()
{
}
```

to your file for an empty definition. If you need to do more in `p4`, add whatever code you want to.

---

**Update**

You just need to add p4.cpp to the set of files in your project.

Comment: I just realized that I forgot to add the p4.cpp file here. In the project, the main.cpp and p4.cpp file are in the same project. I'll add it to the main post right now.

Comment: Both files are in the same project though.

Comment: @underspring3000, it can't be. Perhaps you are confused because the file is in the file system. Presence of a file in the file system does not automatically put the file in the project.

Comment: I can show you a screenshot of it right now. http://imgur.com/gallery/Lti4o

Comment: @underspring3000 Any way you can do a full build and add the build output to your question?

Comment: @underspring3000, I am out of ideas.

Comment: Yo @underspring3000, instead of `void p4();` in main, use `extern void p4();`, and see if that solves the issue. It could be that the function definition is searched for in main.cpp instead of acknowledging that it could be defined somewhere else

Comment: @smac89, that won't make any difference.

Comment: @RSahu I am too :(

Comment: @underspring3000, one more idea is to use header files. Create a file called `p4.hpp` and put `void p4();` in that file. Remove `void p4();` from `main.cpp`, and replace it with `#include "p4.hpp"`. Compile and run. NOTE, if you have a c++ compiler installed on your machine, you can test this by running `c++ main.cpp p4.cpp -o app && ./app.exe`. The fact is that this is a codeblocks specific issue, and there is only so much that one can say to help you at this point. You need to raise this issue on a forum that deals with codeblocks

Comment: @smac89 just tried and it doesn't work either :(

Comment: @user4581301, yea like I said, this is very much related to codeblocks as I cannot reproduce by simply compiling on the command line (also I'm not on windows). See if this [link](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Common_problems_and_solutions) helps, and look for more help that is specific to codeblocks

Comment: @smac89 "You need to raise this issue on a forum that deals with codeblocks –"  - or read one of the thousands of other questions on this site with the same problem

Comment: `extern void p4();` means exactly the same as `void p4();`